# PyQt, How to switch transparent-setting for subwindow

Tags: pyqt5

I want switch WindowTransparentForInput statement of sub-window.
At following code, I wrote, subwindow will close instead switch the statement.

Could you please to point the problem?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw, QtGui as qtg, QtCore as qtc

class Main(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mainWindow = qtw.QWidget(self)
        self.mainWindow.setGeometry(100,100,200,200)
        label = qtw.QLabel('Main window', self)
        self.switch = qtw.QCheckBox('Transparent for input on sub window', self)
        self.switch.setChecked(False)
        self.switch.stateChanged.connect(self.switchAction)

        mainLayout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        mainLayout.addWidget(label)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.switch)

        self.subwindow = qtw.QWidget()
        self.subwindow.setGeometry(150,100,200,200)
        sublabel = qtw.QLabel('Sub window', self.subwindow)

        self.show()
        self.subwindow.show()
    
   
    def switchAction(self):
        if self.switch.isChecked:
            self.subwindow.setWindowFlags(qtc.Qt.WindowTransparentForInput | qtc.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        else:
            self.subwindow.setWindowFlags(qtc.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by modifying `switchAction()` as follow.
I'm sorry for your notation.

```
def switchAction(self):
    if self.switch.isChecked():
        self.subwindow.close()
        self.subwindow.setWindowFlags(self.subwindow.windowFlags() | qtc.Qt.WindowTransparentForInput)
        self.subwindow.show()
    else:
        self.subwindow.close()
        self.subwindow.setWindowFlags(self.subwindow.windowFlags() & ~qtc.Qt.WindowTransparentForInput)
        self.subwindow.show()
```

Comment: You don't need to close the window, just show it again, as [explained in the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop): "This function calls setParent() when changing the flags for a window, causing the widget to be hidden. You must call show() to make the widget visible again.."

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to verify that it would be available by simply removing "self.subwindow.close()".